# Extracting multiple values from a sentence in single cell with same preceding value. eg. Player 1, Player 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Im trying to extract just the Player numbers from the sheet below.

What is the best way to extract just "Player + (player number)" ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP is using Google Sheets, there are Google Sheets' functions that will help extract the output.

1. Insert another column. It will be used to display the results.
2. In this example the inputs are in column A, the outputs are in column B. In cell B2, enter the formula:

```gs
=JOIN(CHAR(10), REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(Player \d+)","($1)")))
```

Drag the formula to fill the other cells.

[image: Result - Google Sheets]

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used PowerQuery to extract the data from Wikipedia, transform into the format in your post, then extract the players into a new table, with a link to the original data. I include this simply because I did it to get the same data as you and it was an interesting exercise for me and I hope it might be interesting for others.

To get directly to the answer to your question, please scroll down to the words **ANSWER BELOW** in bold text.

First, I use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Web, and I enter the address:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_Game#Episodes
```

[image]

I select the Episodes table:

[image]

And I click Transform. The data in PowerQuery look like this:

[image]

Because of the format of the Wikipedia table, the description of each episode is repeated for each of the other columns (No., Title, Directed by, Written by, Original release date). And each episode has two rows - the first with all the other information, and the second with the description repeated.

There is also a 6th column, where the first row is blank and the second row has the description.

[image]

First, I use Add Column>Index Column>From 1, to add an index:

[image]

Now, I add a column to indicate whether the index is odd or even. I use Add Column, Custom Column, like this:

[image]

Now I open the Queries pane on the left, right click the Episodes query and choose 'Duplicate'. This creates 'Episodes (2)'. I right-click that and rename it to Descriptions.

Now I filter the Descriptions query on IndexIsOdd=FALSE. I remove the Index column. I rename Column6 to 'Description', then I remove every column except 'Description' by selecting the columns I want to remove, then right-clicking and using 'Remove Columns'. Then, I add a new Index column, again starting from 1. So that now, I have this:

[image]

Now, I return to the 'Episodes' query and filter IndexIsOdd=TRUE. I remove the Column6, Index and IndexIsOdd columns. I also change the data type of the 'No.' column to Whole Number.

Next, I use Home>Merge Queries, and configure it like this:

[image]

This gives me:

[image]

I click the double-arrow at the top of Descriptions and configure it like this:

[image]

So, now I have the table formatted correctly.

[image]

**ANSWER BELOW**

To get the player numbers, I select the Descriptions column and right-click and use Split Column>By Delimiter, and configure like this:

[image]

Here I have entered "Player " (note the space at the end) as the delimiter.

The result:

[image]

There are now some rows where the description begins with a player number, and some that do not. I will filter for the relevant rows, then extract the number into a new column, then prepend the word "Player " to the number.

I add a new custom column, configured like this:

[image]

The formula:

```
if Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.Start([Description],3)), type number) then "Player " & Text.Start([Description],3) else ""
```

[image]

Now I just filter the Player column to exclude blanks, then hide the Description column. Then I use Home>Close & Load after making any other changes I might want to make (or not):

[image]

Here is the descriptions query:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_Game#Episodes")),
    Data1 = Source{1}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{"No.", type text}, {"Title", type text}, {"Directed by", type text}, {"Written by", type text}, {"Original release date", type text}, {"Column6", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "IndexIsOdd", each Number.IsOdd([Index])),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"IndexIsOdd", type logical}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([IndexIsOdd] = false)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "IndexIsOdd", "No.", "Title", "Directed by", "Written by", "Original release date"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column6", "Description"}}),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Added Index1"
```

And the Episodes query:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_Game#Episodes")),
    Data1 = Source{1}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{"No.", type text}, {"Title", type text}, {"Directed by", type text}, {"Written by", type text}, {"Original release date", type text}, {"Column6", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "IndexIsOdd", each Number.IsOdd([Index])),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"IndexIsOdd", type logical}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([IndexIsOdd] = true)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Column6", "Index", "IndexIsOdd"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"No.", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type2", {"No."}, Descriptions, {"Index"}, "Descriptions", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Descriptions" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Descriptions", {"Description"}, {"Description"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Descriptions", {{"Description", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("Player ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Description"),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Description", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type3", "Player", each if Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.Start([Description],3)), type number) then "Player " & Text.Start([Description],3) else ""),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Player] <> "")),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Description", "Directed by", "Written by", "Original release date"}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Player", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type4"
```

Comment: Nice work! Thanks for the detailed answer. you might wanna replace instances of Player names with Player numbers for analysis. :)